# Looking for a serif for body text to pair with headings set in Verlag for a website

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation, font-pairing

I've looked at the pairings with other HFJ fonts like Sentinel, Chronicle, and Mercury, and while I prefer Sentinel over the other two, I'm not quite ready to commit to it.

Does anyone have any suggestions, or any advice on how to go about exploring possibilities? I'm not particularly experienced in this.

[image]

(This will mostly be used for a website, but may see some print applications as well.)

Comment: That's not *really* the logo is it?

Comment: Heh. Nope, someone else inserted that image into my question...

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a fake Printsheet Specimen with the «Verlag» and a serif font
   (But no Lorem Ipsum).
2. Search for, let's say 10 Serif fonts.
3. Put these fonts into the speciemen, 1 Serif + «Verlag» per page.
4. Print it out & Hang it on the wall.
5. Stand in front of it.
6. Let your eye choose what feels best.